# how to use Data URI for images in WP?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a HTMl file that should converted to WP and WooCommerce. In that file, the previous coder used Data URI for `product images` and `banner images` etc.
I want to know how should I use data URI with dynamic images which will be uploaded by users ? how should I display that using `the_post_thumbnail` ?

Or even the broader question... Is it wise to use data URI in this context ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data URIs don't cache. So you have the same overhead each page request instead of allowing the user to cache those image requests. For product and banner images it doesn't make much sense to take extra processing power to convert them on the fly (each request) or pre-process them which means they'll be stored in the database. It's possible... but I wouldn't say I can recall anyone ever doing it that way with WP.

Comment: For me, that was weird also to use Data URIs for thumbnails, because I heard that best use case for this is on small icons etc. 
Thanks for your response @jgraup. I'm eager to know other opinions.

Comment: Small is fine to quickly show content (icons) but bad on anything large.

Comment: You most certainly can cache the base64 versions of images with wp_cache_set() / wp_cache_get().

Comment: @PaulSchreiber - Sure, you can store binary data in memory cache or db, but why? If it's static content it's better served from a CDN. Sure, it's possible to store in other ways but wouldn't be considered best practice. If a client browser can cache a URL, there will be less load on a server as far as processing + memory for current and future requests. Also, this question centers around `the_post_thumbnail` which would have been uploaded into the WP Media Library with a reference to the image at different sizes.

Comment: You'd be caching ASCII data, not binary data. Why? Because reads from memcache are much faster than reads from a filesystem.

Comment: Cool, cool. Sure ASCII, not binary... either way, I guess your point is the OP should use memcache for uploaded user generated content. 4 years later, my viewpoint is still to use a CDN and save your memory for things that can't rely it. I would say it scales better but at the end of the day it depends on system architecture and traffic.